# Finding data in a belongs to relationship in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am trying to find the account associated with the current user in an ember project. I am able to get the users id and pass it to a handlebars script via `{{account.user.id}}`. All my attempts to find an account with this user ID in my model hook, however, have been unsuccessful.

My current model hook in routes/my-account.js:

```
model (params) {
    let accountID = this.store.query('account', { filter: { user: { id:currentUser} } });
    console.log(accountID.id);
    return this.get('store').findRecord('account', accountID);
  }
```

accountID is returning as an ember class, but I cannot seem to parse any data from it. How would I go about getting the ID from the returned ember class in order to pass it to my get request?

Comment: Where is `currentUser` coming from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get and set properties from and to Ember objects, you have to use `get` and `set`, e.g.:

```
console.log(account.get('id'));
```

More to the point, though, your `.query` will (or should, at least) return an array of `account` models matching the filter. It will be wrapped in a promise—because it's an asynchronous network call—so you'll need to `.then` it. And you probably just want to grab the first account:

```
model() {
  return this.store.query('account', { filter: { user: { id: currentUser } } })
    .then(function(accounts) {
      return accounts.get('firstObject');
    });
}
```

If you have a proper {json:api}, you can just get the `user`, and then get its `account` relationship from e.g. `/api/users/:id/account`. Your model hook would look something like:

```
model() {
  return this.store.findRecord('user', currentUser)
    .then(function(user) {
      return user.get('account');
    });
}
```

Comment: This is successfully pinging my server and getting a 200 back, but it seems to be bouncing off my front end. When I try to console log accounts in the `.then`, nothing appears in my terminal. Why do you think this is, and how would I go about fixing it?

Comment: @d00medman 1. Make sure your console is set up to show everything. 2. It's possible the response is coming back 200 but the payload is malformed somehow and Ember Data is choking on it. Add a `.catch` to the above and console.log (or console.error) the response.

Comment: Alright, I plugged in my .catch and it returned an error reading
`TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`. How can I go about resolving this error?

Comment: @d00medman In the network tab of your developer tools you can filter by XHR and click on the request to see the response payload. Make sure it's not horribly malformed in an obvious way. Are you using {json:api}? What's your backend? You may need to customize your adapter and/or serializer.

Comment: I am using a standard rails API for my back end. In the response tab, it's saying that there is no response data available. What are the implications of this? Does this mean the problem is in fact on my back end? If so, where is a good place to start looking for problems?

Comment: @d00medman At this point I usually drop down to the command line (or a tool like Postman) to start poking at my API to make sure it's returning what I expect it to return, in the format I expect it in. Unfortunately, there really is no such thing as a standard Rails API for Ember Data... implementations can vary wildly. Come find us in #-ember-data on Slack if you need more help!

Comment: So it seems that part of the problem was that my index method on the back end was broken. I have fixed it, and now I am getting back every single user from my database. This is not exactly the behavior I want, but it is absolutely a step in the right direction. I imagine the next step here would be to find which of the accounts returned has a userID which matches that of the current user, then return that? Why do you imagine the specifications applied by the filter method are failing here?

Comment: @d00medman Great! Unfortunately, filter functionality is completely optional and implementation-specific. I'm guessing the index method on your backend doesn't implement filter, or if it does, you're not formatting the request in the way it expects.

Comment: Hmm, would it make sense to simply have my back end fire a show request which queries based on the user id? If so, how would I go about calling this from my front end?

Comment: @d00medman If you have a proper {json:api}, you should be able to get e.g. `/api/users/:id/account`. I'll update my answer to show this more clearly.

Comment: this.store.query expects an array..did you try accountID.objectAt(0).get('id')?

Comment: I was actually able to hack a solution together on the front end in my handlebar scripts which throws away all the returned values without an `:editable` value which gets associated w/the current user on the back end.